# Hiding Divs On Click In Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

I am fairly new to Angular2.I have an app that has a search field, that allows a user to search for a painting of mine. When a match is found a preview div appears and upon clicking that div, a bigger div is displayed, with info about the painting.When the user is done looking at that and wants to search for another, I want them to be able to make it go away by clicking it.Right now, I have figured out how to get the div to do disappear when the user clicks on it.  But if the user searches for a new painting, when they click on the preview div, the bigger div doesn't display.I think it probably has something to do with the state of the application at that point, but I'm not 100% sure since I'm new to Angular2, and this is why I'm turning to you for assistance.  You can test the behavior I have described above at this link: https://mazzo-angular-app.herokuapp.com

Thanks hope you can help,
CMazz

painting-details.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {Painting} from './painting';

@Component({
  selector: 'painting-details',
  templateUrl: 'partials/paintingdetails.html',
  inputs: ['painting'],
  styleUrls: ['css/search-details.css']
})

export class PaintingDetailsComponent{

isHidden: boolean;

constructor(){
    this.isHidden = true;
}

onClick(): void{
    console.log('button clicked yo');
    this.isHidden = !this.isHidden;
}

}
```

paintingdetails.html: This is the larger div, that gets embedded when the preview div is clicked. This div goes away when clicked.  But if a new search is executed,and the preview div is clicked, this div does not display.  Is 
it because its state is still "hidden"?

```
<section *ngIf="isHidden" (click)='onClick()' class="card paintinginfo 
clearfix">

  <div class="painting cf">
  <img src="../../../assets/images/{{painting.shortname}}.jpg" alt=" 
    {{painting.name}}">
   <h1>{{painting.name}}</h1>
   <div class="info">
   <h3>{{painting.reknown}}</h3>
   <div class="longbio">{{painting.bio}}</div>
   </div>
 </div>
</section>
```

search.component.html: The div below with class 'paintingslist' is the preview div that displays when a match is found.  As you can see when it is clicked, it shows the painting in the div with class list 'painting' in paintingsdetails.html.  Each time after the first search, and this div 
'paintingslist' is clicked, the div with the class list 'painting' does 
not show again.

```
<div class="paintingsearch">
<div class="card search">
<h1 >Répertoire des Oeuvres</h1>
<input [(ngModel)]="query" placeholder='Type "Stegostarus" or "Color 
         Explosion"...'>
<label>search <span *ngIf="query"> for: {{query}}</span></label>
</div>
</div>
<ul *ngIf="query" class="paintingslist cf">
<li (click)="showPainting(item); query='';" 
      class="painting cf" *ngFor="let item of (paintings) | find:query">
        <painting-item class="content" [painting]=item></painting-item>
</li>
</ul>
<painting-details *ngIf="currentPainting" [painting]="currentPainting"> 
     </painting-details>
```

search.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Painting } from './painting';
import { PaintingItemComponent } from './painting-item.component';
import { PaintingDetailsComponent } from './painting-details.component';
import { SearchPipe } from './search-pipe';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search',
  templateUrl: './partials/search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./css/search.component.css']
})
export class SearchComponent{ 
    paintings = PAINTINGS;
    currentPainting: Painting;

    showPainting(item) {
      this.currentPainting = item;
    }

var PAINTINGS: Painting[] = [
  {
      "name": "Color Explosion",
      "shortname": "colorExplosion",
      "reknown": "Acrylic on Cardboard",
      "bio": "I couldn't get enough color."
  }, {
      "name": "Back Street Boys",
      "shortname": "backStreetBoys",
      "reknown": "Acrylic on Cardboard",
      "bio": "I wouldn't want to wander down some alley and find this crew..."
  }, {
      "name": "Arroz Con Pollo",
      "shortname": "arrozConPollo",
      "reknown": "Acrylic on Canvas",
      "bio": "This is Jean Michel Basquiat. I can only admire."
  }, {
      "name": "Stego Starus",
      "shortname": "stegoStarus",
      "reknown": "Acrylic on Cardboard",
      "bio": "This was one of my favorite dinos when I was a kid."
  }, {
      "name": "Two Nobodys",
      "shortname": "twoNobodys",
      "reknown": "Acrylic on Canvas",
      "bio": "These two the best of friends. "
  }, {
      "name": "Number One",
      "shortname": "numberOne",
      "reknown": "Acrylic on Cardboard",
      "bio": "I will always have a special place reserved for this one."
  },
  {
      "name": "Couch Fun",
      "shortname": "couchFun",
      "reknown": "Acrylic on Cardboard",
      "bio": "I consider this my best I guess."
  }
]
```

Comment: Try the [hidden] attribute

Comment: So instead of *ngIf="isHidden" you're saying to use [hidden]="isHidden"?

Comment: Please add search.component.ts

Comment: @CMazz why are you setting  `query=''` onclick of `<li>` that's why the `<ul *ngIf="query">` gets hidden after click

Comment: Will do Patryk Gulas

Comment: @CMazz <section> will be hidden after click because you are setting it on (click) event, but once it is hidden it's not being reset.

Comment: Updated original post to add search.component.ts Patryk Gułaś

Comment: Niladri what would resetting it look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image is not showing again because `currentPainting` is not set to null and `PaintingDetailsComponent` doesn't rerender (contructor is not fired again to reset `isHidden` so that's still false). In your painting-details.component.ts emit an event to inform parent about hiding:

```
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import {Painting} from './painting';

@Component({
  selector: 'painting-details',
  templateUrl: 'partials/paintingdetails.html',
  inputs: ['painting'],
  styleUrls: ['css/search-details.css']
})

export class PaintingDetailsComponent{
  @Output() onHide = new EventEmitter();

  isHidden: boolean;

  constructor(){
    this.isHidden = true;
  }

  onClick(): void{
    this.isHidden = !this.isHidden;
    this.onHide.emit();
  }
}
```

And in your search.component subscribe to that event and set `currentPainting` to `null`.

```
<div class="paintingsearch">
  <div class="card search">
    <h1 >Répertoire des Oeuvres</h1>
    <input [(ngModel)]="query" placeholder='Type "Stegostarus" or "Color 
         Explosion"...'>
    <label>search <span *ngIf="query"> for: {{query}}</span></label>
  </div>
</div>
<ul *ngIf="query" class="paintingslist cf">
  <li (click)="showPainting(item); query='';" 
      class="painting cf" *ngFor="let item of (paintings) | find:query">
    <painting-item class="content" [painting]=item></painting-item>
  </li>
</ul>
<painting-details 
    *ngIf="currentPainting" 
    [painting]="currentPainting" 
    (onHide)="resetCurrentPainting()"
></painting-details>
```

---

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Painting } from './painting';
import { PaintingItemComponent } from './painting-item.component';
import { PaintingDetailsComponent } from './painting-details.component';
import { SearchPipe } from './search-pipe';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search',
  templateUrl: './partials/search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./css/search.component.css']
})
export class SearchComponent{ 
  paintings = PAINTINGS;
  currentPainting: Painting;

  showPainting(item) {
    this.currentPainting = item;
  }

  resetCurrentPainting() {
    this.currentPainting = null;
  }

  var PAINTINGS: Painting[] = [
  {
    "name": "Color Explosion",
    "shortname": "colorExplosion",
    "reknown": "Acrylic on Cardboard",
    "bio": "I couldn't get enough color."
  }, {
    "name": "Back Street Boys",
    "shortname": "backStreetBoys",
    "reknown": "Acrylic on Cardboard",
    "bio": "I wouldn't want to wander down some alley and find this crew..."
  }, {
    "name": "Arroz Con Pollo",
    "shortname": "arrozConPollo",
    "reknown": "Acrylic on Canvas",
    "bio": "This is Jean Michel Basquiat. I can only admire."
  }, {
    "name": "Stego Starus",
    "shortname": "stegoStarus",
    "reknown": "Acrylic on Cardboard",
    "bio": "This was one of my favorite dinos when I was a kid."
  }, {
    "name": "Two Nobodys",
    "shortname": "twoNobodys",
    "reknown": "Acrylic on Canvas",
    "bio": "These two the best of friends. "
  }, {
    "name": "Number One",
    "shortname": "numberOne",
    "reknown": "Acrylic on Cardboard",
    "bio": "I will always have a special place reserved for this one."
  },
  {
    "name": "Couch Fun",
    "shortname": "couchFun",
    "reknown": "Acrylic on Cardboard",
    "bio": "I consider this my best I guess."
  }
]
```

You can even remove `isHidden` from `PaintingDetailsComponent`.

Comment: I'm going to try this Patryk Gułaś.  Thanks for the taking the time if it works I'll make sure to check your response as the solution.

Comment: Oh man Patryk Gułaś yer a freakin' genius buddy. I had a good sense it had to do with the state of the application. That is, that the parent was not aware of any subsequent hiding events, and that connection was made, via the emit method notifying the component, of an onHide event, and the call to reset the current painting to null.  Just an FYI I did have to keep the isHidden property explicitly defined as boolean, because I got an error in the build process complaining that isHidden, did not exist on type PaintingDetailComponent. In any case, my application works as intended now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting isHidden to false on click in PaintingDetailsComponent and never resetting it. I am guessing that you are also setting currentPainting and not clearing that, which means your PaintingDetailsComponent never gets re-initialized. I would fire an event using [EventEmitter](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter) in your onclick that resets the currentPainting in your search component.

```
onReset() {
  this.currentPainting = null;
}
```

That should fix your problem immediately. You can probably even get rid of isHidden altogether.

Comment: Probably just setting it to null. That depends on its initial state in your search component.

Comment: Malfus thanks for responding.  I am new to EventEmitters as well.